# pyqt: How can I just print the file name after selecting the file (python)?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have created FileDialog to browse file.
After choosing the file, I want to get the name of the file only! But I always get full path.. and this is my Code:

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_2_handler)

def pushButton_2_handler (self):
    self.open_dialog_box()

def open_dialog_box(self):
    filename=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    print(filename[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pathlib` module:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = Path("C:/users/foobar/desktop/file.txt")
>>> path.name
'file.txt'
>>> path.stem
'file'
>>> path.suffix
'.txt'
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well file paths go like `blah\blah\blah\filename` so all you need to do is loop back until you find a `\` and use that.

```
for index in range(len(filename[0])-1, 0,-1):
    if filename[0][index] == "\\": 
        filename[0] = filename[0][index+1:]
        break
```

you could also split up the string by `\` and use the last one like

```
filename[0] = filename[0].split("\\")[-1]
```

or use `os`

```
import os
filename[0] = os.path.basename(filename[0])
```

Comment: why is the most reasonable way listed last? Frankly it should be the only one. There is no need to use loops and costume code when there is a library function doing exactly that...